# Python3 OpenID-library

Tags: python, python-3.x, openid, tornado

I search for OpenID-library, which works with python3. I need to be an OpenID-provider and OpenID-consumer. tornado.auth provides only consumer functionality. What I can use to implement provider functionality, or how it can be implemented with tornado?

Does anybody uses python3-openid (fork of python-openid)? How it works?

Answer (score 2):

[python3-openid](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python3-openid) is the Python 3 version of `python-openid`, which has been more or less the reference library for OpenID in Python for several years. So it should implement everything you need. (Disclaimer: I ported `python3-openid` over and am the maintainer of the PyPI package).

However, for Tornado you will need a non-blocking implementation, ideally using Tornado's `HTTPClient` classes, and currently `python3-openid` does not provide that -- if you'd like to implement it, though, I'll gladly work on your pull request!

Answer (score 1):

I went with **[pyoidc](https://github.com/OpenIDC/pyoidc)** because it is listed as a "*Certified Relying Party Library*" on the official list of "*Certified OpenID Connect Implementations*" directly on the website for the [OpenID standard](https://openid.net/developers/certified/).  It runs on Python 3.5+ and also doubles as a full OAuth2.0 implementation.

I know this is an old post but it is still relevant.  One should not screw around when it comes to things like security and authentication, it could very well save your job to stick with officially recommended or certified libraries - if anything goes wrong, at least your choice of authentication library can't be called into question!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this, i found it on pypi:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python3-openid/3.0.1

Comment: I've still don't tried this. I am interesting, does anybody tried.

Comment: am sorry, dident try it myself, but you should notice that the library that you'll use must be non-blocking!

Comment: thank you. I understand. Even think about how to implement your own server without libraries (i need to provide only one identificator - single-user openid provider).

Comment: the openID is slow! and using it in the blocking way will cost you several seconds!